# CSS Top of Element 100px From Bottom of Window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to use absolute positioning to place the top of a block-level element 100px from the bottom of the window?

In my application, I cannot anchor this element a given number of pixels from the top of the page, because several elements on the page have an unknown height, and I would have to use JavaScript to dynamically measure, size, and place these elements.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you don't know the height of the element you wish to place 100px from the bottom?

Comment: @greener I don't know that either, since it changes.

Comment: No, not possible without calculating using JS

Comment: can't you just use position:fixed and give it a bottom:100px;?

Comment: @JustinBicknell Fixed and absolutely positioned are very different animals

Comment: @Madbreaks - i get that, just wondering if that is an option - better than using javascript no?

Comment: @JustinBicknell No, my page combines a weird application of `fixed` and `absolute`. This element needs to be `absolute`, while the element prior to it needs to be `fixed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible using `position:absolute` without leveraging JavaScript or some server side logic based on the height of the element being positioned (but it sounds like you don't know that either).

Comment: Yep, that is what I have been doing, but I was hoping CSS had a way of doing this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To position items relative to the browser window you want to use `position:fixed`, not `position:abslute`. Then you just set `bottom: 100px` or however far you like away from the bottom of the window.

Comment: My page combines a weird application of `fixed` and `absolute`. This element needs to be `absolute`, while the element prior to it needs to be `fixed`. Sorry I didn't clarify.

Comment: Okay, it's hard to see unless we have code samples. One thing you want to remember is that `absolute` is relative to the parent element, so if the parent element had `position:relative` for example, the `top` and `left` attributes from the child element would be relative to the parent. That's something to consider and try but I don't think this applies for `fixed` though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but maybe this could help:

```
<div class='b'>
    <div class='a'>
        element
    </div>
</div>

.a {
    margin-bottom:-100%;
}

.b {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmB9U/

Comment: Op said the height of your element `a` is unknown and varies

Comment: What happens when you fill `a` with content?

Comment: If I add a bunch of text: http://jsfiddle.net/pmB9U/1/ the top remains at 100px from the bottom. It doesn't look pretty but that's how I read the question..

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible if can live with a scrollbar which does not span the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Emulate position:fixed</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    header
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
</body>

</html>
```